# почему [произошло что-то](,) не уточняется

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "не уточняется" и почему ? 
"Почему 15-летний ученик выбился из струи и сразу не пошел мочить своих одноклассников не уточняется. "
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему 15-летний ученик выбился из струи и сразу не пошел мочить своих одноклассников - не уточняется.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Тире для обозначения смысловой паузы ставится при инверсии изъяснительного придаточного: Он приедет, но когда – не знаю. Хорошо, что они венчаются, а как жить будут – кто знает. Как рассказывал учитель – долго слушал у окна я.

Comment: думаю, там применимы и запятая, и тире, нет строгого правила

http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827507.html
пункт 24.6, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: Я ориентировалась на Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142. Кроме того, при значительной распространенности изъяснительной части без паузы/тире трудно обойтись, так как в случае постановки запятой предложение прочитывается неясно.

Answer (score 0):

Сложноподчиненное предложение, запятая ставится. Но в контексте с "выбился из струи" и "мочить" она не обязательна. Гулять так гулять.

Comment: думаю, там применимы и запятая, и тире, нет строгого правила orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827507.html пункт 24.6, но спасибо за ответ